# How can I assign this as separate variables?

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a string that looks like this `"%one_two_three_four"`

How can I set:

`$a = "one"
$b = "two"
$c = "three"
$d = "four"`

Comment: without just doing `substr(1,4)` of course

Comment: You could use `preg_replace_callback`. Pull everything between `%` and the end of string then explode on `_`

Comment: @K.Randy can you be more specific about the string please? Is it just that string or pattern or  how does it vary?

Answer (score 4):

Keeping it very simple you could do this

```
$in = "%one_two_three_four"

// remove the %
$t = str_replace('%', '', $in);

// split the string on each underscore into an array
$t = explode('_', $t);

// assign the array values to scalar variables
$a = $t[0];
$b = $t[1];
$c = $t[2];
$d = $t[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with

- [`sscanf` — Parses input from a string according to a format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)

**Example**

```
sscanf('%one_two_three_four', '%%%[^_]_%[^_]_%[^_]_%s', $a, $b, $c, $d);
```

This will parse the string in the first argument according to the pattern in the second argument and assign any matched values to the remaining arguments.

The pattern explained:

- `%%` is a literal %
- `%[^_]` is everything but an underscore
- `_` is a literal underscore
- `%s` is any string

---

You can also use

- [`preg_split` — Split string by a regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and
- [`list` — Assign variables as if they were an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

**Example**

```
list($a, $b, $c, $d) = preg_split(
    '#[%_]#', 
    '%one_two_three_four', 
    null, 
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
);
```

This will split the string by the given pattern and assign the results from the found matches. The fourth argument makes sure we only get non-empty results.

The pattern means: split by by underscore or percent.

Comment: Excelent answer, I do not know why somebody downvoted it, +1 from my side.

Comment: @Starkeen thanks. I am puzzled what the dv is for, too.